# Backbone Form not working

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm new to Backbone. I'm trying a simple page which takes the name of the user, stores it in a model and renders it in a different page using handlebars. This is as far as I could get. The page doesnt show any errors but doesnt render anything also.

HTML code :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">

       <script src="jquery.js"></script>
      <script src="underscore.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="backbone.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

      <script type="text/template" id="name">
        <form method="Post">Name:
        <input type="text" name="name" id="input" />
        <input type="submit" value="submit" id="form-submit" />
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
    </form>
    </script>

    <title>Form8</title>

    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="View">
        </div>
```

Script:

```
<script>


        FormModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

            defaults: {
                name: ''
            }
        });

        FormCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model: FormModel
        });


        FormView = Backbone.View.extend({
            el: '#View',
            events: {
                'click #form-submit': 'OnFormSubmit'
            },
            initialize: function () {


               this.render();

            },
            OnFormSubmit: function () {
                template1 = _.template($("#name").html());
            },

            render: function () {

               $(this.el).html($("#name").html());

                return this;
            }

        });
         var FormView = new FormView();

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try rendering the form:

```
var formView = new FormView();
formView.render()
```

Comment: Is the template placed rightly? coz it doesnt render anything on the page

Comment: I was getting a blank page with the code you have posted. When I changed var formView = new FormView(); things worked. I was able to see the name input box with the submit button. You don't require formView.render() since you are already calling render method from the initialize method.

Comment: @Balaji By changing var formView = new FormView(); could you see the name being rendered on to the page again? If yes, can you please post a jsfiddle of the same code. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Everything is correct in your code, just put your JavaScript code before body closing tag OR put your code in

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Your code here
});
```

Comment: Aghabekkyan, Tried it. Nothing is being displayed on the page